# A simple program to demonstrate memory leak in Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

I am looking for a simple program that can demonstrate memory leak in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder, why not mark the question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/EffectiveJava.aspx

See Item 6.

Answer (score 2):

Memory leak are for example if you have references that are not necessary any more but can't get catched by the garbage collector.

There are simple examples e.g. from IBM that shows the principle:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/0816_GuptaPalanki/

Answer (score 1):

```
 Vector v = new Vector();
 while (true)
 {
     byte b[] = new byte[1048576];
     v.add(b);
 }
```

This will continuously add a 1MB byte to a vector until it runs out of memory

Answer (score 0):

A great example from a great book: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=6

Comment: @Esko: Not for me. Perhaps it's a geographic issue ?

Comment: Well if it's geographic, then you better edit in the content of that link since this site is very much international.

Comment: @Esko: I didn't say there's something special with my location (trust me, there isn't). I meant there's something completely wrong with yours. If all else fails use a web proxy (I'm almost sure you'll get *that* right). If that fails too: http://pcproblems.files.wordpress.com/2007/05/dilbert2007029326511.gif

Answer (score 0):

Let's first defined what is a memory leak in Java context - it's a situation when a program can mistakenly hold a reference to an object that is never again used during the rest of the program's run.

An example to it, would be forgetting to close an opened stream:

```
class MemoryLeak {

    private void startLeaking() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
        URLConnection conn = new URL("www.example.com/file.txt").openConnection();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));        

        while (br.readLine() != null) {
            input.append(br.readLine());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MemoryLeak ml = new MemoryLeak();
        ml.startLeaking();
    }
}
```